# How to delete the data forcibly when the metadata is abnormal?

Tags: dolphindb

When I run the below code:

```py
dropDatabase("dfs://dolphin_day_bar")
```

There is an error:

```py
<ChunkInRecovery>deleteSubChunks failed on '/dolphin_day_bar', chunk 0224d999-38c1-1ebc-ce46-0cdf7ea6903b is in RECOVERING state
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods. The first one:

```py
dbName="/stocks_orderbook"
fileCond=dbName + "%"
t=exec substr(file,strlen(dbName)) from rpc(getControllerAlias(),getClusterChunksStatus) where file like fileCond, state != "COMPLETE"
dropPartition(database("dfs:/"+dbName),t,,true)
```

the second one:

```py
deleteChunkMetaOnMaster("dfs://compoDB/20170808/0_50")
deleteReplicas(node,chunkID)
```